# How to remove element from list in KDB?

Tags: kdb, q-lang

For instance, I have:

```
x: (`a`b!(1;2); (); `a`b!(3;4))
```

and I want to remove the `()`. I have tried using `?` (match)

```
x[x ? not ()]
```

but that just gives `()`.

What is the correct expression?

**Background**

I often use `peach` to execute a series of queries, and often some will return missing data in the form of `()`. Hence I want to remove the `()` and get back to a nice table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use except as well:

```
q)x except 1#()
a b
---
1 2
3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you are returning tables already (rather than dictionaries), you could always just `raze` and that would be enough to get rid of the empty list. Technically, it is appended, but if you append an empty list on a list, you get the original list. Recall that a table is simply a list of dictionaries, so this remains the case here as well.

```
//I'm enlisting your dictionaries,
//so that they become tables and then raze
q)raze @[x; 0 2; enlist]   
a b
---
1 2
3 4
```

Snippets such as `raze f each x` or `raze f peach x` are very common, and I suspect this is the idiom that would be best for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

() is an empty list. So it has count of zero. Therefore we can use:

```
q)x where not 0 = count each x
a b
---
1 2
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight more generic way to get rid of unwanted elements :

```
q)x where not x~\:()
a b
---
1 2
3 4

q)x where not x~\:`a`b!(1;2)
()
`a`b!3 4
```